# VB sciprt + how redirect output from CMD window to file

Tags: linux, windows-xp, vba, vbscript

I wrote the following VB script in order to run commands from WIN XP on a Linux machine and redirect the output command to out.txt file ( under C:\ )

I don’t understand why output from the command window is not written to out.txt file.

What’s wrong with the line

```
      Sh.Run "cmd /k  & CMD >> ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True
```

My full VB script:

```
 'TARGET_HOST  - Linux machine

 Const TARGET_HOST = "18.20.183.99"
 const PATH =  "cat /etc/hosts" 
 const LOGIN = "root"
 const PASS = " dingdong "
 Const PLINKPATH="""C:\SPUTNIK\plink.exe"""

 Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

        CMD = " echo y | " &   PLINKPATH  & " -ssh -pw " & PASS & LOGIN & "@" & " "   &  TARGET_HOST & " " & PATH 


 Sh.Run "cmd /k  & CMD >> ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True

  Set Sh = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are including the `CMD` variable you created inside the string instead of as a variable.

Try something like:

`Sh.Run "cmd /k" & CMD & " >> ""C:\out.txt""" , 1, True`